# Checking to make sure a MYSQL Db Dump sql file is useable

Tags: mysql

We have an automated script to take the MySQL DB dump and then push it to the S3 bucket. Our other environments fetch this DB Dump hourly and restore it.

Sometimes DB dump command fails and pushes a corrupt DB dump to the S3 bucket which creates a problem for other environments. Is there any way to check the sanity of DB dump file before importing it?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60755/verify-mysqldump-backup-is-corruption-free

Comment: Check the exit code and only upload the dump on success?